# XCode 7 compile multiple targets

Tags: xcode, compilation, xcode7

Can I compile multiple targets with one click? I've 2 targets but even that's cumbersome to switch and compile while iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As apple official developers website pointed out, you can edit building scheme to determine which targets are built when you choose Run, Test, Profile, Analyze, or Archive from the Product menu. 
So try to follow below steps :

> From the Scheme toolbar menu, choose a scheme and run destination.
>
> From the same menu, choose Edit Scheme to display the scheme dialog.
>
> In the left column, select Build.
>
> For each target, select the actions for which to build the target.
>
> Click Close.

So that's it. For more information take a look at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeBuild.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH2-SW1).

Comment: No I haven't, I will be checking now!

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you :) Will select the answer when it's eligible.